# Protected route returning malformed request.json() to React frontend

Tags: express, fetch

I am trying to make a fetch request to a protected route on my Express app. The route is working fine when the request is made with Postman, I get the response sent. But when I attempt a fetch request from the frontend, I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0`.

The fetch request from the frontend

```js
export const getProtectedMessage = async (token) => {
  const URI = 'http://localhost:3001'; //TODO save root uri to environment variable
  const bearer = 'Bearer ' + token;
  return fetch(`${URI}/me`, {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': bearer,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Entry point for express app index.js

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
import routes from './routes/index.js';
import db from './db/index.js';

dotenv.config();
db(process.env.DB_NAME);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(routes);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(404);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The routes

```js
import express from 'express';
import * as auth from '../controllers/auth.js';
import expressjwt from 'express-jwt';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();

const jwtCheck = expressjwt({
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  algorithms: ['sha1', 'RS256', 'HS256']
});

router.post('/sign-up', auth.signUp);
router.post('/sign-in', auth.signIn);
router.get('/me', jwtCheck, auth.profile);

export default router;
```

The controller for the protected route

```js
export function profile(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('A secret resource - only for authenticated users');
}
```

Comment: You are sending a string(`res.status(200).send('A secret resource - only for authenticated users');`) from your server and front-end side you are trying to parse it to json(`res.json()`. which is throwing error.

Comment: Try this - `res.status(200).json({screct:"##########"})`

Answer (score 0):

In the end the error was how I was sending the response. Maybe there's a more appropriate way to do it, but changing the controller to the following worked.

```js
export function profile(req, res) {
  // res.status(200).send('A secret resource - only for authenticated users'); // WRONG
  res.status(200).json('Resource only for authenticated users'); // works!
}
```

One more thing, it's also good practice to check the application header in the fetch request. Sometimes, you don't know what you're getting from the backend could be json, could be text.

```js
export const getProtectedMessage = async (token) => {
  const URI = 'http://localhost:3001'; //TODO save root uri to environment variable
  const bearer = 'Bearer ' + token;
  return fetch(`${URI}/me`, {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      Authorization: bearer,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then((res) => {
      const contentType = res.headers.get('Content-Type').split(';')[0];
      if (contentType === 'application/json') {
        return res.json();
      }
      console.log(contentType);
      if (contentType === 'text/html') {
        return res.text();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```